# GWT Multiple File Upload issue using in iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, gwt, file-upload, mgwt

I have a web app built using mgwt but even using some GWT widgets as well. In the web app, I have a GWT form panel where the user has to upload two images which could be using camera or select from the photo library on the phone. I am using multiple GWT file upload widget for this. These images then are sent to the server, saved at a particular location on the server, and after some comparison of these images, a matching score is calculated and saved in the database.

It's working fine with Android or laptops but when I try to use iPhone to use the web app and upload two images, the problem is it's giving the same file name photo.jpg to both uploads. At the server only one image is getting saved because of the same file name. The comparison is done with itself as both the images are given the same file name. Hence the matching fails.

I was looking for a work around for this issue where the file upload would give different file names to both uploads in iPhone. It works fine on Android.

Comment: This sounds like a platform bug relating to MGWT. Have you checked their bug tracker to see if something has been raised already?

Comment: Yes, i have but nothing is in there...

Comment: OK, are you able to raise a new bug there? The core devs may even be able to offer a workaround. (It's fine to ask about it here, but it seems sufficiently bug-like to warrant a report).

Comment: I have already put it in the google group forum for MGWT but I dont know if it is a problem with the GWT FileUpload Widget, not sure where I could post it for GWT.

Comment: May we have a link to your Google Group post? It is customary when cross-posting to several forums to give the URL of other posts, so readers can check to see if you have obtained an answer elsewhere.